# OnItemLongClickListener blocks OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, adapter, onclicklistener

I have a listview with checkboxes. on press of an item, it goes to another activity. on long press, the checkboxes are revealed and the current item is selected. When OnItemClickListener is implemented, it works fine alone, but when OnItemLOngClickListener is used, the normal click isn't registered

My Code:

1. Activity :

   ```
   myAdapter = new MyCursorCheckboxAdapter(UserViewLibraryActivity.this,cursor,0);
       bookList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.android_list);
       bookList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

       bookList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                 /* Stuff */

               Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), swipeBorrowActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("number", i);
               intent.putExtra("USER_NAME", user);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
           }
       });
       bookList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               inSelectMode=true;
               myAdapter.setCheckMode(true);
               CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
               checkBox.setChecked(true);
               return true;
           }
       });
   ```

   2. Adapter:

      ```
      package com.example.blah.library1;

      import android.content.Context;
      import android.database.Cursor;
      import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
      import android.view.LayoutInflater;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.ViewGroup;
      import android.widget.CheckBox;
      import android.widget.TextView;

      /**
       * Created by blah on date.
       */

      public class MyCursorCheckboxAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
          private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;
          private boolean[] checkedArray;
          Checker checker;
          int checkCount;
          boolean isCheckMode;

          public boolean[] getSelection() {
              return checkedArray;
          }

          public int getCheckCount() {
              return checkCount;
          }

          public void setCheckMode(boolean checkMode) {
              this.isCheckMode = checkMode;
              notifyDataSetChanged();
          }

          public boolean getCheckMode() {
              return isCheckMode;
          }

          public interface Checker {
              public void isAnyChecked(boolean isChecked);
          }


          public MyCursorCheckboxAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
      super(context, c, flags);
      cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      checkedArray = new boolean[c.getCount()];
      checkCount = 0;
      isCheckMode = false;
      try {
          checker = ((Checker) context);
      } catch (ClassCastException e) {
          throw new ClassCastException("Activity Must Implement Checker");
      }
      checker.isAnyChecked(false);

          }

          @Override
          public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

      return cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_checkbox, parent, false);
                  }

          @Override
          public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      // Log.d("Cursor :", cursor.getString(1));
      TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
      title.setText(cursor.getString(1));
      TextView author = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listAuthor);
      author.setText(cursor.getString(2));
      TextView copies = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listCopies);
      copies.setText(cursor.getString(4));

      final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
      checkBox.setVisibility(isCheckMode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
      final int position = cursor.getPosition();
      if (cursor.getInt(4) == 0) {
          // Log.d("Position :", ((Integer)cursor.getPosition()).toString());
          checkBox.setEnabled(false);
      }
      checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
              if (isChecked) {
                  //Log.d("Checkbox :","isChecked "+Integer.toString(position));
                  checkCount++;
                  if (checkCount == 1)
                      checker.isAnyChecked(true);
                  checkedArray[position] = true;

              } else {
                  // Log.d("Checkbox :","isNotChecked "+Integer.toString(position));
                  checkCount--;
                  if (checkCount == 0) {
                      checker.isAnyChecked(false);
                      checkedArray[position] = false;
                      // Log.d("Checker :","No items are checked");
                  }
              }
          }
      });

          }
      }
      ```
2. My list item layout:

EDIT: Removing both attributes android:clickable="true" and android:longClickable="true" makes it work

Comment: Try after removing `android:longClickable="true"` in XML

Comment: Wow! removing both `longClickable` and `clickable` works! but why?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently removing both `android:clickable="true"` and `android:longClickable="true"` makes it work. (Why i dont understand)